# Converting IP address to number in tcl

Tags: tcl, ip-address

i want to convert string to number to use in **SCP** command. can someone please help?

```
set ip "192.168.1.2"
scp:root@$ip//etc/dev/
```

it doesn't replace `$ip` with the IP i had set.

how do I convert the IP to number as the scp command is expecting number rather than string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a library to do that. [tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) has an [IP address manipulation module](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html):

```
package require ip
set ip "192.168.1.2"
set num [ip::toInteger $ip]
puts $num
puts [ip::intToString $num]
```

```
-1062731518
192.168.1.2
```

This looks odd: `scp:root@$ip//etc/dev/`

Recall that Tcl evaluates commands like `command word ...`, and there's no whitespace in that "scp" command, so Tcl will try to find a command named "scp:root@192.168.1.2//etc/dev/" -- I bet it can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about converting *any* string to a number, but rather an IP address.  In Tcl *most* everything is a string, so you just use the expr command for math and it will do the conversion as necessary.  Notice how in my implementation below inside `expr` I simply refer to `[lindex $octets $i]` which is a string derived from splitting the IP address, yet the command still runs as expected.

The below is a naive implementation of what you are really asking for: converting an IP address to a number (integer); you would want to enhance it with various validations (length of the segments array, min/max of each segment, etc.) -- this is why a library as suggested in the other answer may be a better way, not to mention possibly being equipped to handle ipv6 which I simply ignore ;)

[Here's an explanation of the implementation in general](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/IP2Integer.jsp); please anybody feel free to edit with a better one.  A note on my implementation: by reversing the list, I make it trivial to multiply the last octet by 256^0, the next to last octet by 256^1, etc, the power being the lindex.

```
set ip "192.168.1.2"
set ip_as_int 0
set octets [lreverse [split $ip .]]

for {set i 0} {$i < 4} {incr i} {
    set ip_as_int [expr {256 ** $i * [lindex $octets $i] + $ip_as_int}]
}

puts $ip_as_int ;#3232235778
```